# apresentar o resultado de um foreach fora do loop

Tags: php, loop, foreach

Olá,

Preciso de apresentar o resultado de um foreach fora do loop. A forma como tenho feito só apresenta um resultado.
O que estou eu a fazer mal?

```
  //Check bad words


$badWords = array('palavra1', 'palavra2', 'palavra3');

$string = "A palavra1 é igual a palavra2 que é diferente da palavra3";
$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $string, 
                $matches
              );

if ($matchFound) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {
    $p[i] = $word;
    $i++;
  }
  echo '<div class="notice notice-danger">A historia contém palavras censuradas, não poderá ser publicada. (';
  print_r($p[i]);
  echo ' ) </div>';

  die();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens um erro um pouco grave no `$p[i]` sendo que `i` não existe (nem `$p` nesse ponto, mas em php um array pode ser declarado quando é populado a primeira vez).

Aproveitando o código com mas devidas correções:

```
$badWords = array('palavra1', 'palavra2', 'palavra3');

$string = "A palavra1 é igual a palavra2 que é diferente da palavra3";
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $string, 
                $matches
              );

$p = array();
if ($matchFound > 0) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {
    $p[] = $word;
  }
  echo '<div class="notice notice-danger">A historia contém palavras censuradas, não poderá ser publicada. (';
  print_r($p);
  echo ' ) </div>';

  die();
}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/CYD5w0)

Tens maneiras melhores e sem regex de conseguir isto:

```
$badWords = array('palavra1', 'safgfsa', 'palavra2', 'palavra3', 'pal4');

$string = "A palavra1 é igual a palavra2 que é diferente da palavra3";

$p = array();
foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $v) {
    $v = str_replace([',', '.', ';', '?', '!', ':'], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], $v); // eliminar entropia, retirar pontuacao de acordo com a nossa lingua
    if(in_array($v, $badWords)) {
        $p[] = $v;
    }
}

$p = array_unique($p);
if(count($p) > 0) {
    echo "foram encontradas palavras<br>";
    echo implode(', ', $p); // imprimir palavras encontradas separadas por virgula e espaco
}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/Fv6tIY)

OUTPUT:

```
foram encontradas palavras
Array
(
    [0] => palavra1
    [1] => palavra2
    [2] => palavra3
)
```

Comment: E como é que removo do resultado a palavra "Array"? Neste momento o resulta é:(Array
(
    [0] => palavra1
    [1] => palavra2
    [2] => palavra3
) e eu queria que fosse apenas (palavra1, palavra2, palavra3)

Comment: Consegui echo implode( ', ', $p );

Comment: @BrunoSerrano, não pensei que o problema era esse, pensei que fosse acerca do erro que estava a dar